# Finding equation of line with given slope

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Find the distances of the point (1,2) from a straight line. The slope is given to be 5 and the line passes through the intersection point of the lines $x+2y = 5$ and $x - 3y = 7$

Obviously I could find the intersection of the two lines, and then use it to find the equation of the wanted line. However, upon solving the two equations, the values come out to be in fractions. There has to be an easier method to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Write the equations of the given lines in the form $l=0$. Then consider the line 
$$(x+2y-5)+\lambda(x-3y-7)=0.$$
For every $\lambda$ this represents a line passing through the intersection of the given lines (with the exception of the second line itself). This can be rewritten as 
$$x(1+\lambda)+y(2-3\lambda)-(5+7\lambda)=0.$$
From this you can compute $\lambda$ by using the fact that the slope is $5$. This gives you the equation of the line. Now you can find the distance.

Note: if the answer is in fractions so be it. They are also part of the number system:-)